# GPO to map drives conditionally

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, mappeddrive

We have a file server that is sharing out user drives from //server/user$.  We also have webDav enabled so it can be access externally by https://fileserver.company.com/user.

My challenge is to map all workstations to the webDav share, while all servers get mapped to the share directly (server 08r2 has no webDav client).  I'm trying not to unnecessarily enable loopback processing to get this done (boss is scared of it, and i have no fight left).

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this via a single GPO (or multiple if necessary)?

Comment: why are you using WEBDAV at all?  I don't believe you can map an HTTPS share

Answer (score 3):

GP Preference with item level targeting

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753566.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Mounting shared drives is a user-level issue, so your best chance is to write a user login script that checks the current hostname, computer account, or other identifying feature of the host to see whether to mount `//server/user$` or `https://server.example.com/user`.